# How to shrinkwrap npm modules without local dependencies

Tags: npm, shrinkwrap

I tried to maintain package.json with the list of node modules dependencies. when I call npm install it installs the node modules.and generates a folder for it in my app. I call the npm shrinkwrap. But this generates the dependency on the local node module

```
  "dependencies": {
"async": {
  "version": "0.2.5",
  "from": "async@0.2.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.5.tgz"
},
```

when I upload the app to the appfog server it can install from the npm-shrinkwrap.json. So Ideally I want to remove the node modules folder and just pass the shrinkwrap.json file. But it has this "from". I had in the past generated the shrinkwrap & it didn't have the "from" field in there.
How to generate without "from"/ can I just get a shrinkwrap file from package.json. so my app will be leaner. I can maintain all the node module globally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question.

Shrinkwrap does not install, package, upload or do anything to your dependencies.

All it does is scan your **installed** node_modules and record the versions (recursively) into a file.  Invoking `npm install` after that file is defined becomes repeatable, which is a [principle of software engineering](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2011/02/on-repeatable-builds/).

"from" was introduced a few months back.  The `npm shrinkwrap` command seems to set it to the URL from which a module was installed.  This is probably for portability.  `npm install` takes a module name, consults a registry (whose URL is configurable as an `npm config` setting) and installs it.  I could take the same `package.json` and `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, put them on another machine and theoretically get a different result if that machine's `npm config` settings point it to a different registry.  Therefore, embedding the resolved URL in the shrinkwrap file adds an additional level of repeatability to `npm install`

See the [npm config man page](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html) for details of setting the registry parameters.

According to npm issue 3145 on github, the "from" setting is known to cause backwards-compatibility issues with pre-1.2.x npm systems.  Upgrading is the only resolution.

https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3145

Comment: I guess the problem is with appfog which would not recognize the "from" field. If I remove the "from" field from npm-shrinkwarp.json it installs it in the server. Is there a way to generate the shrinkwrap.json without the "From" field.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Here is a github issue where isaacs basically says the only option is to upgrade npm on the box you are install the package onto.  https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3145

Comment: shrinkwrap gets you much further but alone alone is not necessarily enough , packages can be unpublished, the registry can be down for maintenance, or you can be offline. See the justification for shrinkpack for more info: https://github.com/JamieMason/shrinkpack/#justification.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for shrinkpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shrinkpack

from the doc:

> Shrinkpack complements the npm shrinkwrap command by maintaining a node_shrinkwrap directory in your project, containing the exact same tarballs that npm install downloads from https://registry.npmjs.org.
>
> The rest of the npm install process is exactly the same. The only difference is that no network activity is necessary when installing and building your project. The node_shrinkwrap directory can be ignored in your editor (much like is done with the node_modules directory) but is instead checked into source control.