# appfog - npm shrinkwrap mass errors

Tags: node.js, npm, appfog

Im trying to learn node.js using appfog free server, so here is my app.js file:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
console.log('asd');
function start(route) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        route(pathname);
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello pd!!!");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 1337, null);
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name":"hello-node",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":""
    }
}
```

npm-shrinkwrap.json

```
    {
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "semver": {
      "version": "2.0.8",
      "from": "semver@latest"
    },
    "ini": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "ini@latest"
    },
    "slide": {
      "version": "1.1.4",
      "from": "slide@latest"
    },
    "abbrev": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "from": "abbrev@latest"
    },
    "graceful-fs": {
      "version": "1.2.2",
      "from": "graceful-fs@latest"
    },
    "minimatch": {
      "version": "0.2.12",
      "from": "minimatch@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "sigmund": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "from": "sigmund@~1.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
    "nopt": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "from": "nopt@latest"
    },
    "rimraf": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "from": "rimraf@2.2"
    },
    "request": {
      "version": "2.21.0",
      "from": "request@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "qs": {
          "version": "0.6.5",
          "from": "qs@~0.6.0"
        },
        "json-stringify-safe": {
          "version": "4.0.0",
          "from": "json-stringify-safe@~4.0.0"
        },
        "forever-agent": {
          "version": "0.5.0",
          "from": "forever-agent@~0.5.0"
        },
        "tunnel-agent": {
          "version": "0.3.0",
          "from": "tunnel-agent@~0.3.0"
        },
        "http-signature": {
          "version": "0.9.11",
          "from": "http-signature@~0.9.11",
          "dependencies": {
            "assert-plus": {
              "version": "0.1.2",
              "from": "assert-plus@0.1.2"
            },
            "asn1": {
              "version": "0.1.11",
              "from": "asn1@0.1.11"
            },
            "ctype": {
              "version": "0.5.2",
              "from": "ctype@0.5.2"
            }
          }
        },
        "hawk": {
          "version": "0.13.1",
          "from": "hawk@~0.13.0",
          "dependencies": {
            "hoek": {
              "version": "0.8.5",
              "from": "hoek@0.8.x"
            },
            "boom": {
              "version": "0.4.2",
              "from": "boom@0.4.x",
              "dependencies": {
                "hoek": {
                  "version": "0.9.1",
                  "from": "hoek@0.9.x",
                  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz"
                }
              }
            },
            "cryptiles": {
              "version": "0.2.1",
              "from": "cryptiles@0.2.x"
            },
            "sntp": {
              "version": "0.2.4",
              "from": "sntp@0.2.x",
              "dependencies": {
                "hoek": {
                  "version": "0.9.1",
                  "from": "hoek@0.9.x",
                  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "aws-sign": {
          "version": "0.3.0",
          "from": "aws-sign@~0.3.0"
        },
        "oauth-sign": {
          "version": "0.3.0",
          "from": "oauth-sign@~0.3.0"
        },
        "cookie-jar": {
          "version": "0.3.0",
          "from": "cookie-jar@~0.3.0"
        },
        "node-uuid": {
          "version": "1.4.0",
          "from": "node-uuid@~1.4.0"
        },
        "mime": {
          "version": "1.2.9",
          "from": "mime@~1.2.9"
        },
        "form-data": {
          "version": "0.0.8",
          "from": "form-data@0.0.8",
          "dependencies": {
            "combined-stream": {
              "version": "0.0.4",
              "from": "combined-stream@~0.0.4",
              "dependencies": {
                "delayed-stream": {
                  "version": "0.0.5",
                  "from": "delayed-stream@0.0.5"
                }
              }
            },
            "async": {
              "version": "0.2.9",
              "from": "async@~0.2.7"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "which": {
      "version": "1.0.5",
      "from": "which@1"
    },
    "tar": {
      "version": "0.1.17",
      "from": "tar@0.1.17",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.17.tgz"
    },
    "fstream": {
      "version": "0.1.22",
      "from": "fstream@latest"
    },
    "block-stream": {
      "version": "0.0.6",
      "from": "block-stream@*"
    },
    "inherits": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "from": "git://github.com/isaacs/inherits"
    },
    "mkdirp": {
      "version": "0.3.5",
      "from": "mkdirp@0.3.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz"
    },
    "read": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "from": "read@~1.0.3",
      "dependencies": {
        "mute-stream": {
          "version": "0.0.3",
          "from": "mute-stream@~0.0.2"
        }
      }
    },
    "lru-cache": {
      "version": "2.3.0",
      "from": "lru-cache@latest"
    },
    "node-gyp": {
      "version": "0.10.2",
      "from": "node-gyp@latest"
    },
    "fstream-npm": {
      "version": "0.1.4",
      "from": "fstream-npm@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "fstream-ignore": {
          "version": "0.0.6",
          "from": "fstream-ignore@~0.0.5"
        }
      }
    },
    "uid-number": {
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "from": "../uid-number"
    },
    "archy": {
      "version": "0.0.2",
      "from": "archy@0.0.2"
    },
    "chownr": {
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "from": "../chownr"
    },
    "npmlog": {
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "from": "npmlog@latest"
    },
    "ansi": {
      "version": "0.1.2",
      "from": "ansi@~0.1.2"
    },
    "npm-registry-client": {
      "version": "0.2.25",
      "from": "npm-registry-client@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "couch-login": {
          "version": "0.1.17",
          "from": "couch-login@~0.1.15"
        }
      }
    },
    "read-package-json": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "read-package-json@1",
      "dependencies": {
        "normalize-package-data": {
          "version": "0.2.0",
          "from": "normalize-package-data@~0.2",
          "dependencies": {
            "github-url-from-git": {
              "version": "1.1.1",
              "from": "github-url-from-git@~1.1.1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "read-installed": {
      "version": "0.2.2",
      "from": "read-installed@latest"
    },
    "glob": {
      "version": "3.2.1",
      "from": "glob@3.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.2.1.tgz"
    },
    "init-package-json": {
      "version": "0.0.10",
      "from": "init-package-json@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "promzard": {
          "version": "0.2.0",
          "from": "promzard@~0.2.0"
        }
      }
    },
    "osenv": {
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "from": "osenv@latest"
    },
    "lockfile": {
      "version": "0.3.4",
      "from": "lockfile@0.3.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile/-/lockfile-0.3.4.tgz"
    },
    "retry": {
      "version": "0.6.0",
      "from": "retry"
    },
    "once": {
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "from": "once"
    },
    "npmconf": {
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "from": "npmconf@latest",
      "dependencies": {
        "config-chain": {
          "version": "1.1.7",
          "from": "config-chain@~1.1.1",
          "dependencies": {
            "proto-list": {
              "version": "1.2.2",
              "from": "proto-list@~1.2.1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "opener": {
      "version": "1.3.0",
      "from": "opener@latest"
    },
    "chmodr": {
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "from": "chmodr@latest"
    },
    "cmd-shim": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "cmd-shim@"
    },
    "sha": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "sha@~1.0.1"
    },
    "editor": {
      "version": "0.0.4",
      "from": "editor@"
    },
    "child-process-close": {
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "from": "child-process-close@",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/child-process-close/-/child-process-close-0.1.1.tgz"
    },
    "npm-user-validate": {
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "from": "npm-user-validate@0.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-user-validate/-/npm-user-validate-0.0.3.tgz"
    }
  }
}
```

When im trying to update my app using `af update ikap`, it gives me lots of errors

```
    Error: Application [ikap] failed to start, logs information below.
====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2013-07-06 17:48:46 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Installing dependencies. Node version 0.8.14
Installing semver@semver@latest from local path
Installing ini@ini@latest from local path
Installing slide@slide@latest from local path
Installing abbrev@abbrev@latest from local path
Installing graceful-fs@graceful-fs@latest from local path
Installing minimatch@minimatch@latest from local path
Installing sigmund@sigmund@~1.0.0 from local path
Installing nopt@nopt@latest from local path
Installing rimraf@rimraf@2.2 from local path
Installing request@request@latest from local path
Installing qs@qs@~0.6.0 from local path
Installing json-stringify-safe@json-stringify-safe@~4.0.0 from local path
Installing forever-agent@forever-agent@~0.5.0 from local path
Installing tunnel-agent@tunnel-agent@~0.3.0 from local path
Installing http-signature@http-signature@~0.9.11 from local path
Installing assert-plus@assert-plus@0.1.2 from local path
Installing asn1@asn1@0.1.11 from local path
Installing ctype@ctype@0.5.2 from local path
Installing hawk@hawk@~0.13.0 from local path
Installing hoek@hoek@0.8.x from local path
Installing boom@boom@0.4.x from local path
Installing hoek@hoek@0.9.x from local path
Installing cryptiles@cryptiles@0.2.x from local path
Installing sntp@sntp@0.2.x from local path
Installing hoek@hoek@0.9.x from local path
Installing aws-sign@aws-sign@~0.3.0 from local path
Installing oauth-sign@oauth-sign@~0.3.0 from local path
Installing cookie-jar@cookie-jar@~0.3.0 from local path
Installing node-uuid@node-uuid@~1.4.0 from local path
Installing mime@mime@~1.2.9 from local path
Installing form-data@form-data@0.0.8 from local path
Installing combined-stream@combined-stream@~0.0.4 from local path
Installing delayed-stream@delayed-stream@0.0.5 from local path
Installing async@async@~0.2.7 from local path
Installing which@which@1 from local path
Installing tar@tar@0.1.17 from local path
Installing fstream@fstream@latest from local path
Installing block-stream@block-stream@* from local path
Installing inherits@git://github.com/isaacs/inherits from git source
Installing mkdirp@mkdirp@0.3.5 from local path
Installing read@read@~1.0.3 from local path
Installing mute-stream@mute-stream@~0.0.2 from local path
Installing lru-cache@lru-cache@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry lru-cache@lru-cache@latest
Failed getting the requested package: lru-cache@lru-cache@latest
Installing node-gyp@node-gyp@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry node-gyp@node-gyp@latest
Failed getting the requested package: node-gyp@node-gyp@latest
Installing fstream-npm@fstream-npm@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry fstream-npm@fstream-npm@latest
Failed getting the requested package: fstream-npm@fstream-npm@latest
Installing uid-number@../uid-number from registry
Package is not found in npm registry uid-number@../uid-number
Failed getting the requested package: uid-number@../uid-number
Installing archy@archy@0.0.2 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry archy@archy@0.0.2
Failed getting the requested package: archy@archy@0.0.2
Installing chownr@../chownr from registry
Package is not found in npm registry chownr@../chownr
Failed getting the requested package: chownr@../chownr
Installing npmlog@npmlog@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry npmlog@npmlog@latest
Failed getting the requested package: npmlog@npmlog@latest
Installing ansi@ansi@~0.1.2 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry ansi@ansi@~0.1.2
Failed getting the requested package: ansi@ansi@~0.1.2
Installing npm-registry-client@npm-registry-client@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry npm-registry-client@npm-registry-client@lat
est
Failed getting the requested package: npm-registry-client@npm-registry-client@la
test
Installing read-package-json@read-package-json@1 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry read-package-json@read-package-json@1
Failed getting the requested package: read-package-json@read-package-json@1
Installing read-installed@read-installed@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry read-installed@read-installed@latest
Failed getting the requested package: read-installed@read-installed@latest
Installing glob@glob@3.2.1 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry glob@glob@3.2.1
Failed getting the requested package: glob@glob@3.2.1
Installing init-package-json@init-package-json@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry init-package-json@init-package-json@latest
Failed getting the requested package: init-package-json@init-package-json@latest

Installing osenv@osenv@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry osenv@osenv@latest
Failed getting the requested package: osenv@osenv@latest
Installing lockfile@lockfile@0.3.4 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry lockfile@lockfile@0.3.4
Failed getting the requested package: lockfile@lockfile@0.3.4
Installing retry@retry from registry
Package is not found in npm registry retry@retry
Failed getting the requested package: retry@retry
Installing once@once from registry
Package is not found in npm registry once@once
Failed getting the requested package: once@once
Installing npmconf@npmconf@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry npmconf@npmconf@latest
Failed getting the requested package: npmconf@npmconf@latest
Installing opener@opener@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry opener@opener@latest
Failed getting the requested package: opener@opener@latest
Installing chmodr@chmodr@latest from registry
Package is not found in npm registry chmodr@chmodr@latest
Failed getting the requested package: chmodr@chmodr@latest
Installing cmd-shim@cmd-shim@ from registry
Package is not found in npm registry cmd-shim@cmd-shim@
Failed getting the requested package: cmd-shim@cmd-shim@
Installing sha@sha@~1.0.1 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry sha@sha@~1.0.1
Failed getting the requested package: sha@sha@~1.0.1
Installing editor@editor@ from registry
Package is not found in npm registry editor@editor@
Failed getting the requested package: editor@editor@
Installing child-process-close@child-process-close@ from registry
Package is not found in npm registry child-process-close@child-process-close@
Failed getting the requested package: child-process-close@child-process-close@
Installing npm-user-validate@npm-user-validate@0.0.3 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry npm-user-validate@npm-user-validate@0.0.3
Failed getting the requested package: npm-user-validate@npm-user-validate@0.0.3

====> /logs/stdout.log <====

asd
```

As i understand, this is because my nodejs is missing some packages, so im installing them one by one (first successful installs is because ive installed some of them). But when im trying to `npm shrinkwrap` :

```
    C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap>npm shrinkwrap
npm ERR! Error: Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! extraneous: archy@0.0.2 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-te
st-shrinkwrap\node_modules\archy
npm ERR! extraneous: child-process-close@0.1.1 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\p
ackages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\child-process-close
npm ERR! extraneous: chmodr@0.1.0 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-t
est-shrinkwrap\node_modules\chmodr
npm ERR! extraneous: cmd-shim@1.1.0 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm
-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\cmd-shim
npm ERR! extraneous: editor@0.0.4 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-t
est-shrinkwrap\node_modules\editor
npm ERR! extraneous: lockfile@0.3.4 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm
-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\lockfile
npm ERR! extraneous: npm-user-validate@0.0.3 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\pac
kages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\npm-user-validate
npm ERR! extraneous: npmlog@0.0.3 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-t
est-shrinkwrap\node_modules\npmlog
npm ERR! extraneous: opener@1.3.0 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-t
est-shrinkwrap\node_modules\opener
npm ERR! extraneous: read-installed@0.2.2 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packag
es\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\read-installed
npm ERR! extraneous: retry@0.6.0 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-te
st-shrinkwrap\node_modules\retry
npm ERR! extraneous: sax@0.5.4 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test
-shrinkwrap\node_modules\sax
npm ERR! extraneous: sha@1.0.1 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test
-shrinkwrap\node_modules\sha
npm ERR! extraneous: uid-number@0.0.3 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\n
pm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\uid-number
npm ERR! extraneous: block-stream@0.0.6 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages
\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\block-stream
npm ERR! extraneous: fstream-npm@0.1.4 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\
npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\fstream-npm
npm ERR! extraneous: glob@3.2.1 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-tes
t-shrinkwrap\node_modules\glob
npm ERR! extraneous: init-package-json@0.0.10 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\pa
ckages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\init-package-json
npm ERR! extraneous: npm-registry-client@0.2.25 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\
packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\npm-registry-client
npm ERR! extraneous: registry@0.3.0 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm
-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\registry
npm ERR! extraneous: node-gyp@0.10.2 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\np
m-test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\node-gyp
npm ERR! extraneous: npmconf@0.1.1 C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-
test-shrinkwrap\node_modules\npmconf
npm ERR!     at shrinkwrap_ (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\shrinkwrap.js:29:15)

npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\shrinkwrap.js:23:5
npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\ls.js:41:30
npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-inst
alled.js:119:5
npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-inst
alled.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.
js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-inst
alled.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.
js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-inst
alled.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.
js:48:11)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "shrinkwrap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\npm-de
bug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Also, npm install

```
    C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap>npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.17.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/child-process-close/-/child-process-clos
e-0.1.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile/-/lockfile-0.3.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.2.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-user-validate/-/npm-user-validate-0.
0.3.tgz
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.1
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.17.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-user-validate/-/npm-user-validate-0.
0.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/child-process-close/-/child-process-clos
e-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile/-/lockfile-0.3.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-shrinkwrap\npm-de
bug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I just want to learn node.js step-by-step, but i cant even upload my first files to appfog...

Comment: Does your app run locally on your computer? You would need to have it running locally before trying to push to AppFog. Also do you have **git** installed?

Comment: Locally - localhost:1337 doesnt works (console outputs `> C:\www\nodejs>node app.js \n > asd`, localhost works (i got apache). And sorry, i dont know what git is :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shrinkwrap npm modules without local dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406322/how-to-shrinkwrap-npm-modules-without-local-dependencies)